# Best way to lazily update calculated properties by hashing dependent attributes

Tags: python, hash, properties, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to make a bunch of geometric objects which have their intrinsic geometric properties (center point, radius, lengths, etc.), as well as properties to help plot them (like x, y, z coordinates for a triangular mesh, arc resolution, etc.).

Since calculating the x, y, z coordinates is an expensive task for some of the shapes (like a triangular prism with edge rounding), I don't want to do it every time a property is changed, but only when the coordinates are requested.  Even then though, it shouldn't be necessary to recalculate them if the shape's definition hasn't changed.

So my solution has been to create a "hash" which is is simply a tuple of all parameters which define the shape's "state."  If the hash is unchanged, then the previously calculated coordinates can be re-used, otherwise, the coordinates must be recalculated.  So I'm using the hash as a way to store the signature or fingerprint of the shape's definition.

I think what I have works, but I wonder if there are more robust ways to handle this that take advantage of `__hash__` or id's or something.  That feels like overkill to me, but I'm open to suggestions.

Here's my implementation for a sphere.  I'm using Mayavi for plotting at the end, which you can skip/ignore if you don't have Mayavi.

```
#StdLib Imports
import os

#Numpy Imports
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, cos, pi


class Sphere(object):
    """
    Class for a sphere
    """
    def __init__(self, c=None, r=None, n=None):
        super(Sphere, self).__init__()

        #Initial defaults
        self._coordinates = None
        self._c = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
        self._r = 1.0
        self._n = 20
        self._hash = []

        #Assign Inputs
        if c is not None:
            self._c = c

        if r is not None:
            self._r = r

        if n is not None:
            self._n = n

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c

    @c.setter
    def c(self, val):
        self._c = val

    @property
    def r(self):
        return self._r

    @r.setter
    def r(self, val):
        self._r = val

    @property
    def n(self):
        return self._n

    @n.setter
    def n(self, val):
        self._n = val

    @property
    def coordinates(self):
        self._lazy_update()
        return self._coordinates

    def _lazy_update(self):
        new_hash = self._get_hash()
        old_hash = self._hash
        if new_hash != old_hash:
            self._update_coordinates()

    def _get_hash(self):
        return tuple(map(tuple, [self._c, [self._r, self._n]]))

    def _update_coordinates(self):

        c, r, n = self._c, self._r, self._n

        dphi, dtheta = pi / n, pi / n
        [phi, theta] = np.mgrid[0:pi + dphi*1.0:dphi,
                                0:2*pi + dtheta*1.0:dtheta]

        x = c[0] + r * cos(phi) * sin(theta)
        y = c[1] + r * sin(phi) * sin(theta)
        z = c[2] + r * cos(theta)

        self._coordinates = x, y, z
        self._hash = self._get_hash()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    from mayavi import mlab

    ns = [4, 6, 8, 10, 20, 50]

    sphere = Sphere()

    for i, n in enumerate(ns):
        sphere.c = [i*2.2, 0.0, 0.0]
        sphere.n = n

        mlab.mesh(*sphere.coordinates, representation='wireframe')

    mlab.show()
```

As suggested, here's a version that uses a dictionary to store the hash as a key:

```
#StdLib Imports
import os

#Numpy Imports
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, cos, pi


class Sphere(object):
    """
    Class for a sphere
    """
    def __init__(self, c=None, r=None, n=None):
        super(Sphere, self).__init__()

        #Initial defaults
        self._coordinates = {}
        self._c = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
        self._r = 1.0
        self._n = 20

        #Assign Inputs
        if c is not None:
            self._c = c

        if r is not None:
            self._r = r

        if n is not None:
            self._n = n

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c

    @c.setter
    def c(self, val):
        self._c = val

    @property
    def r(self):
        return self._r

    @r.setter
    def r(self, val):
        self._r = val

    @property
    def n(self):
        return self._n

    @n.setter
    def n(self, val):
        self._n = val

    @property
    def _hash(self):
        return tuple(map(tuple, [self._c, [self._r, self._n]]))

    @property
    def coordinates(self):
        if self._hash not in self._coordinates:
            self._update_coordinates()

        return self._coordinates[self._hash]

    def _update_coordinates(self):

        c, r, n = self._c, self._r, self._n

        dphi, dtheta = pi / n, pi / n
        [phi, theta] = np.mgrid[0:pi + dphi*1.0:dphi,
                                0:2 * pi + dtheta*1.0:dtheta]

        x = c[0] + r * cos(phi) * sin(theta)
        y = c[1] + r * sin(phi) * sin(theta)
        z = c[2] + r * cos(theta)

        self._coordinates[self._hash] = x, y, z


if __name__ == '__main__':

    from mayavi import mlab

    ns = [4, 6, 8, 10, 20, 50]

    sphere = Sphere()

    for i, n in enumerate(ns):
        sphere.c = [i*2.2, 0.0, 0.0]
        sphere.n = n

        mlab.mesh(*sphere.coordinates, representation='wireframe')

    mlab.show()
```

Comment: Aren't you just reimplementing a dictionary, but not protecting yourself against hash collisions?  Why not use your tuple as the key in a dictionary?

Comment: Part of why I used sets was so that the hash was an immutable copy and because I originally stored it as a dictionary key (with a throwaway value of `True`).  I'd then do `if self._get_hash() in self._hash_dict` to check if I needed to recalculate.  Then I realized that I could just check equality instead of checking dict membership... so I changed it to essentially `if self._get_hash() != self._hash:` since it's more lightweight.  Also what hash collision might I care about?  The entire state of my shape is stored in the tuple, so if it's equal, it is by definition the same shape.

Comment: Ah, ignore my hash collision comment -- I could have sworn I saw a call to the `hash` function in there but apparently I'm simply illiterate.  I don't understand your reluctance to use a `dict`, though: using a cache_dict is the standard pattern (or an `lru_cache` if that's appropriate.)

Comment: I guess because dicts are for mapping an unordered sequence of keys to values and I don't need all that... I also just watched [Alex Gaynor's 'Fast Python, Slow Python' talk](http://pyvideo.org/video/2627/fast-python-slow-python), which cautions against abusing complex data structures.

Comment: Editted to add an implementation with a dictionary... so is that better/idiomatic/pythonic?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply keep a flag:

```
class Sphere(object):

    def __init__(self, ...): 
        ...
        self._update_coordinates()

    ...

    @c.setter
    def c(self, val):
        self._changed = True
        self._c = val

    ...

    def _lazy_update(self):
        if self._changed:
            self._update_coordinates()

    def _update_coordinates(self):
        ...
        self._changed = False
```

Comment: I thought about that, but then coordinates would be recalculated for the same geometry... like here: `sphere.r = 1; x,y,z=sphere.coordinates sphere.r+=1; sphere.r=sphere.r/2; x,y,z = sphere.coordinates`. The second set of coordinates shouldn't trigger a recalculation because the current set is based on r=1, and r still equals 1.  The fact that r=2 for a moment shouldn't cause unnecessary recalculation (if coordinates were never requested).